# Python - get encoding of file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having difficulty getting the character encoding of a file. The offending code is here:

```
    rawdata = open(file, "r").read()
    encoding = chardet.detect(rawdata.encode())['encoding']
    #return encoding
```

(Code courtesy of Ashish Greycube: https://github.com/frappe/frappe/pull/8061

I've copied a segment of the csv file I'm working on as a more manageable 'test' file. When I run the above code on it, it says it's 'ascii'. That might be part of the problem. Basically, I've found out that I need to know the encoding type for this prpogram.

The error report is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\program.py", line 26, in <module>
    my_encoding = get_file_encoding(data)
  File ".\program.py", line 20, in get_file_encoding
    encoding = chardet.detect(rawdata.encode())['encoding']
  File "C:\Users\stsho\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\chardet\__init__.py", line 38, in detect
    detector.feed(byte_str)
  File "C:\Users\stsho\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\chardet\universaldetector.py", line 211, in feed
    if prober.feed(byte_str) == ProbingState.FOUND_IT:
  File "C:\Users\stsho\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\chardet\charsetgroupprober.py", line 71, in feed
    state = prober.feed(byte_str)
  File "C:\Users\stsho\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\chardet\hebrewprober.py", line 227, in feed
    byte_str = self.filter_high_byte_only(byte_str)
  File "C:\Users\stsho\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\chardet\charsetprober.py", line 63, in filter_high_byte_only
    buf = re.sub(b'([\x00-\x7F])+', b' ', buf)
  File "C:\Users\stsho\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\re.py", line 208, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
MemoryError
PS C:\Users\stsho\dev\csv_sanitizer_1.2> python .\program.py
Please enter filename: ANQAR
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\program.py", line 26, in <module>
    my_encoding = get_file_encoding(data)
  File ".\program.py", line 19, in get_file_encoding
    rawdata = open(file, "r").read()
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ANQAR.csv'
PS C:\Users\stsho\dev\csv_sanitizer_1.2> python .\program.py
Please enter filename: ANQAR
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\program.py", line 26, in <module>
    my_encoding = get_file_encoding(data)
  File ".\program.py", line 19, in get_file_encoding
    rawdata = open(file, "r").read()
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ANQAR.csv'
PS C:\Users\stsho\dev\csv_sanitizer_1.2> python .\program.py
Please enter filename: ANQAR
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\program.py", line 26, in <module>
    my_encoding = get_file_encoding(data)
  File ".\program.py", line 20, in get_file_encoding
    encoding = chardet.detect(rawdata.encode())['encoding']
  File "C:\Users\stsho\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\chardet\__init__.py", line 38, in detect
    detector.feed(byte_str)
  File "C:\Users\stsho\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\chardet\universaldetector.py", line 211, in feed
    if prober.feed(byte_str) == ProbingState.FOUND_IT:
  File "C:\Users\stsho\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\chardet\charsetgroupprober.py", line 71, in feed
    state = prober.feed(byte_str)
  File "C:\Users\stsho\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\chardet\hebrewprober.py", line 227, in feed
    byte_str = self.filter_high_byte_only(byte_str)
  File "C:\Users\stsho\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\chardet\charsetprober.py", line 63, in filter_high_byte_only
    buf = re.sub(b'([\x00-\x7F])+', b' ', buf)
  File "C:\Users\stsho\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\re.py", line 208, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
MemoryError
```

Comment: Error it shows in exception is that: file isn't present. You sure file is present and you haven't mistyped its name?

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
import chardet

rawdata = open(file, "rb").read()
encoding = chardet.detect(rawdata)['encoding']
```

Answer (score 1):

A `MemoryError` usually implies you're trying to load data too large for your memory, either the address space or available storage (RAM + swap/page file space). You seem to be running a 32 bit build of Python, which would limit you to 2 GB of address space; I'd suggest switching to a 64 bit build, as most machines nowadays have more than 4 GB of RAM, and not using a 64 bit build means you can't use most of it.

Additional issue: When you read the file in text mode, you're already assuming you *know* the encoding. Don't do that. Open it in binary mode (`"rb"`) to get the raw, unmodified bytes, so `chardet` gets them directly before you try decoding them in a possibly incorrect encoding.

Comment: Using this:
rawdata = open(file, "rb").read()
encoding = chardet.detect(rawdata)['encoding']

I get encoding as Windows-1252. This is basically just gibberish text, not 'utf-8' or some such that I was hoping for...

Answer (score -1):

like @ShadowRanger said try to build it in 64bit and don't read file in text mode try this

```
enter co rawdata = open(file, "rb").read()
encoding = chardet.detect(rawdata.encode())['encoding']
```

and make sure your file is present and write its name correctly.

Comment: i'm not sure what 'enter co' will do but it returns an error